# Gdal_translate command for SDS having spaces in its name

Tags: modis, gdal-translate

Can anyone help me with using gdal_translate on an HDF4 dataset that a space?

One SDS in the the HDF is:

HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13Q1.A2004001.h08v05.005.2007234070731.hdf":MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI:250m 16 days NDVI

I want to use gdal_translate to extract this as a tif or envi file and I use the following command:

HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13Q1.A2004001.h08v05.005.2007234070731.hdf":MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI:250m 16 days NDVI ndvi.envi

This displays a message "too many command options" and displays the general gdal_translate template and "The following format drivers are configured and support output:" list.

Where am I going wrong? I have used the same command another dataset that does not have spaces like that of between "16 days NDVI" and that works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, your gdal_translate command is incomplete, you don't have the command name or the format argument.

But, you just need to quote the entire string, possibly with escapes. Try just single quotes around it all

```
'HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13Q1.A2004001.h08v05.005.2007234070731.hdf":MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI:250m 16 days NDVI'
```

Comment: Yes, I missed the gdal_translate while asking the question. Sorry about that. I tried out what you suggested: gdal_translate  'HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13Q1.A2004001.h08v05.005.2007234070731.hdf":MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI:250m_16_days_NDVI' ndvi.envi. I get an error:GDALOpen failed - 4
`HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"$data":MODIS_Grid_16DAY_250m_500m_VI:250m_16_days_EVI' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name. Could you please suggest a way to go about this?

Comment: Windows and Linux might behave different on this. Try double quotes instead of single, and double double `""` where you have double now.